# Trying to keep selected div in navbar active after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to keep selected tab active on reload. Tried and checked with some question already been asked here but none of work for me. So far, it the active class correctly jumps on click but the click directs me to a new page and then it switches back to the default active div. Here is my code:

**navbar.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to activities_path, :class => "icon active" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-home icon-selector"></i>
      <p>Home</p>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to new_list_path, :class => "icon" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-edit icon-selector"></i>
      <p>New List</p>
  <% end %>
```

**update_icon.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".icon").click(function () {
$(".icon").removeClass("active");
// $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below
$(this).addClass("active");
 });
});
```

Comment: both files have the same code?? please check your update_icon.js files code.

Comment: Ups! Sorry edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

To store the value for the active class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".icon").click(function () {
$(".icon").removeClass("active");
// $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below
$(this).addClass("active");
localStorage.setItem('selectedTab', 'active');
```

When you reload the page, check if localStorage contains the active value:

```
let tabValue = localStorage.getItem('selectedTab');
if(tabValue !== '') {
  $('icon').addClass(tabValue);
} else {
  tabValue = '';
}
```

Anything stored in localStorage will survive page reloads and closing the browser.

EDIT:

The code below will store the active tab in localStorage, and set the active class on the tab upon page reload

index.html

```
<div class='icon'>
<i class="fas fa-home icon-selector"></i>
<p>Home</p>  
</div>
<div class='icon'>
<i class="fas fa-edit icon-selector"></i>
<p>New List</p>
</div>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".icon").click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('active');
   let text = $(this).find('p').text();
   localStorage.setItem('selectedTab', text);
   $('.icon').find('p').each(function() {
     if($(this).text() !== text) {
     $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
     }
   })
 });
  let selectedTab = localStorage.getItem('selectedTab');
   $('.icon').find('p').each(function() {
     if($(this).text() === selectedTab) {
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     }
   })
});
```

I have a live example at CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxqLXg?editors=1111

If you click on for example the "Home" tab, the "active" class will be set. If you then click on "New List", the "active" class will be removed from the "Home" tab and set on "New List" instead. If you reload the page, localStorage is checked for the lastet clicked tab, and then that tab will get the "active" class. Try out the CodePen example and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second part of the code would I include it in the same file? Not sure exactly how to implement it . Because when I say add class(tabValue) to "..icon" I add it to all icon elements..

Comment: @Emanuel Cohen: Yes, I have edited and reposted an example which should be what you were asking for.

Comment: Awesome thanks!! One question: By default when a user logs in he lands on the home page but he has not clicked on the icon. Will the icon "home" still be set to active?

Comment: @Emanuel Cohen: The Home icon will not be set to active by default, the active class will not be set until the user clicks on a tab. To achieve this you need to check if localStorage contains the property 'selectedTab', and if this is not found set the active class on the Home tab.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`<%= link_to activities_path, :class => "icon <%= 'active' if @active_nav == 'activities' %>" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-home icon-selector"></i>
      <p>Home</p>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to new_list_path, :class => "icon <%= 'active' if @active_nav == 'new_list' %>" do %>
      <i class="fas fa-edit icon-selector"></i>
      <p>New List</p>
  <% end %>`

in your `activities#index`

`@active_nav = 'activities'`

and in `lists#new`

`@active_nav = 'new_list'`